# Fluentmigrator how test if a user defined function (UDF) exists?

Tags: c#, sql-server, fluent-migrator

Is it possible, using FluentMigrator, to verify if a user defined function (UDF) exists before creating it?
I'm using version 3.2.9 and SQL Server

Comment: You should be able to `create or alter function`

Comment: I've been a little more radical than that, since I'm creating the function with SQL, I start by deleting it like this:
IF OBJECT_ID(XXX) IS NOT NULL DROP function [dbo].[XXX]